# Unit Testing 'Employee' is a namespace but used like a type

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

In Visual Studio 2017, I've Project files structured in this way.

**[Source Code]**

```
Project
    Employee (namespace)
         Employee  (.cs file)

Tests (Unit Test within the same solution referencing Project)
     Employee (namespace)
          EmployeeTest (.cs unit test)
```

**Tests/Employee/EmployeeTest.cs**

```
namespace Tests.Employee
{
    [TestClass]
    public class EmployeeTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestConstructor()
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee(); // error

        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
'Employee' is a namespace but used like a type
```

**Question:**

Besides fixing the error, what's the recommended way to structure my files so I don't run into names conflict, There's a requirement that I've to keep the namespace name same as class name and also match the folder structures, can't avoid that.

**Note:**

I'm a newbie to .net development

Comment: What are you referring to as the package? The assembly?

Comment: sorry, got mixed with java, package means namespace, editing my question

Comment: [DO NOT use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx) See also [Eric Lippert's explanation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/)

Comment: Add an aliased using statement to the top of your test file:

using Pkg = Employee;

Then, in your code:

var employee = new Pkg.Employee();

Comment: @KrisVandermotten otherwise I use fully qualified class names in my unit tests

Comment: What do you mean with "otherwise I use fully qualified class names in my unit tests"?

Comment: meaning if the change is inevitable, i've to keep the name space as the type, I've to use to fully qualified class names, later someone suggested the same in an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a namespace and a class with the exact same name (which is usually bad design) so you will have to instantiate your object specifying fully qualified namespaces:

```
var emp = new Project.Employee.Employee():
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Tests.Employee as a namespace.

Change

`namespace Tests.Employee
{
      // rest of the code
}`

To

`namespace EmployeeTests
{
      // rest of the code
}`